# Make top navigation in SASS responsive

Tags: html, css, sass

Here's my SASS code. It works now, but it isn't responsive. It works fine on 1080p with 100% scaling, but anything else and it breaks. I'm not worrying about functionality now, so I just need it to look good

**SASS:**

```
.navigation {
  position: absolute;
  // padding-left: 0.1%;
  z-index: 1000;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 0.5%;
  background-color: transparent;
  & li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    font-family: Bebas Neue;
    color: $color-white;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  &__list {
    &--paragraph {
      font-size: 1.8rem;
      width: 70%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    &--img {
      top: 1rem;
      position: relative;
      right: 3rem;
      left: 5vh;
      width: 6.3rem;
      height: auto;
      padding-right: 50rem;
      // padding-left: 85vh;
    }
    &--item {
      position: relative;
      top: -1rem;
      margin-left: 5rem;
      padding-left: 1rem;
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="naviagation__list">
    <li class="navigation__list--item">
      <p class="navigation__list--paragraph">
        Drink this water of the spring, rest here awhile, we have a long way to go and i can't go on without you.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation__list--item">
      <img src="img/logowhite.svg" alt="canopic logo" class="navigation__list--img" />
    </li>
    <li class="navigation__list--item">Explore</li>
    <li class="navigation__list--item">Store</li>
    <li class="navigation__list--item">Cart</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

re did the navigation

```
.navigation {
  padding-top: 1%;
  z-index: 300;
  max-height: 1vh;
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 1vw;
  background: transparent;
  font-family: $font-def;
  color: $color-white;
  &__1 {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 1rem;
  }

  &__2 {
    display: block;
    margin: auto auto;
    text-align: center;
    height: 6rem;
    width: auto;
  }

  &__3 {
    color: $color-white;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    // bottom: 4rem;
  }
}
```

im still a beginner so don't trust my code completely